# Is it possible to adjust the height of ApplicationBarMenuItem in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have searched for quite a while to find the answer.
Unfortunately, there is not even single one answer can be found on the Internet.

I only have one ApplicationBarMenuItem inside the ApplicationBar which is "About". And after I saw the effect of the "opened" ApplicationBar, I think it is too "fat" (the height of the item is too much, or maybe the line spacing/margin-top and margin-bottom/padding-top and padding-bottom etc...I'm trying to create an image for you, because I don't know how to get a screen shot for that, but anyway I'm sure you know what I mean :))

So here again is the question, is it possible to change the height of ApplicationBarMenuItem in Windows Phone 8?

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't find how to change height of ApplicationBarMenuItem, because the height property is not availble in AppBar. Maybe you can put 'about' as ApplicationBarIconButton.

Comment: @ChrisShao hi chris, thank you for your reply. Yes, I believe I can, but that's not the way I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't change the AppBar menu item height.

But... i think this is the way the appbar looks in any system application you can take a look at, and the user isn't going to be dissapointed by the size, is just the expected size. Only my two cents, but i don't think you need to worry about that.

Comment: true and thanks. I think I should make a request to Microsoft asking them to add this feature into the WP SDK.